# Bash substitution: log when variable is not set

Tags: bash

I use [bash substitutions](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to give neat one-line validation for input, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PARAM1=${1?Error, please pass a value as the first argument"}
# do something...
```

In some cases though, I want to only log a message when something is unset and then continue as normal. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along the lines of

```
test -n "$1" && export PARAM1="$1" || log "\$1 is empty!"
```

should do; here the `test` clause returns true if and only if `$1` is non-empty.

Comment: I want to keep the variable assigned like the `${var...}` syntax would, but log if it's empty/null. Does that make sense?

Comment: I have expanded a bit my answer.  Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: This does not distinguish between `$1` having an empty value and being unset.

Comment: @chepner, provided there is such a need, it would be easy to modify the `test` clause...

Comment: The question specifically caters to the distinction (it uses `${var?msg}`, not `${var?:msg}`.

Answer (score 1):

For regular parameters (in `bash` 4 or later), you can use the `-v` operator to check if a parameter (or array element, as of version 4.3) is set:

```
[[ -v foo ]] || echo "foo not set"
bar=(1 2 3)
[[ -v bar[0] ]] || echo "bar[0] not set"
[[ -v bar[8] ]] || echo "bar[8] not set"
```

Unfortunately, `-v` does not work with the positional parameters, but you can use `$#` instead (since you can't set, say, `$3` without setting `$1`).

```
(( $# >= 3 )) || echo "third argument not set"
```

Before `-v` became available, you would need to compare two default-value expansions to see if a parameter was unset.

```
[[ -z $foo && ${foo:-bar} == ${foo-bar} ]] && echo "foo is unset, not just empty"
```

There's nothing special about `bar`; it's just an arbitrary non-empty string.